# Date and time formatting in iOS

Tags: ios, string, nsdateformatter

I know the NSDateFormatter but I want it like "Yesterday 12:35" and I only got it you concatting two datestring?

```
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setLocale: [NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]];

[dateFormatter setDoesRelativeDateFormatting:YES];

[dateFormatterTime setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
[dateFormatterTime setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateParsed], [dateFormatterTime stringFromDate:dateParsed ] ];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a look at the great [FormatterKit](https://github.com/mattt/FormatterKit) by Mattt Thompson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I could do by honoring the locale.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter.new;
dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = YES;
dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

NSDate *today = NSDate.new;
// "Today, 11:40 AM"
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:today]);

NSDate *tomorrow = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60*60*24];
// "Tomorrow, 11:40 AM"
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tomorrow]);

NSDate *yesterday = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-(60*60*24)];
// "Yesterday, 11:40 AM"
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:yesterday]);

NSDate *dayAfter = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(60*60*24)*2];
// "2/14/13, 11:40 AM"
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dayAfter]);
```

Comment: You can't use 86400 seconds to mean one day. With time changes throughout the world at different dates of the year it doesn't work. You can use NSCalendar instead though.

Comment: This code is to demonstrate the NSDateFormatter I used, not the way to calculate future and past dates. Please @Fogmeister don't down vote my answer, as it addresses the NSDateFormatter question.